# how to change the alias of the username in rest_framework_simplejwt using TokenObtainPairSerializer class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm working on a project where user can register using his mobile no and password( after verifying with otp) what i'm doing is inside username field i'm saving user's phone no. as username is a mandatory field. And I'm using simple_jwt to get access token and refresh token. Everything is working fine

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)


urlpatterns =[
    path('register', RegisterView.as_view() ),
    path('otp/send', SendOtpView.as_view() ),
    path('otp/verify', VerifyOtpView.as_view() ),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),    
]
```

instead of creating a loginSerializer i'm using rest_framework_simplejwt inbuild class TokenObtainPairView

But when i go to the url
`auth/api/token/` it ask me for username and password, which is confusing as a user . how can i change the name of the **username** to **phone**.

I don't have any idea how to do it as I'm new to the djangorestframework

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

class LoginSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=65, min_length=8, write_only=True)
    **phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, source='username')**
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['phone', 'password']
```

[image]
I tried doing this but then it add on another field with the name phone instead of replacing username. I even don't know whether it will work or not .

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Somehow i found a way to do it. I created a model serializer an used an custom token generator method

https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating_tokens_manually.html

**serializers.py**

```
# for creating token manually
def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }
```

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=65, min_length=8, write_only=True)
    phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, source='username')
    tokens = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    
    def get_tokens(self, obj):
        return obj['tokens']
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['phone', 'password', 'tokens']
        
        
    def validate(self, attrs):
        param_phone = attrs.get('username', "")
        param_password=attrs.get('password', '')
        
        if not param_phone.isnumeric():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'phone': ("Only Phone Number is accepted")}
            )
        
        if not len(param_phone) == 10:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'phone': ("Phone Number length can only be of 10 digits")}
            )
        
        
        user = auth.authenticate(username=param_phone, password=param_password)

        if User.objects.filter(username=param_phone, is_active=False).exists():
            raise AuthenticationFailed("Account disabled. Contact admin")
        
        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("Invalid Credential. Try again")
        

        tokens = get_tokens_for_user(user)

        return {
            'username':param_phone,
            'tokens': tokens
        }

        return super().validate(attrs)
```

**views.py**

```
class LoginView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```